# inheriting a class with parameteraized constractor to reuse base properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class

i'm trying to minimize use of constractors in derived classes, and have a base class to hold common properties

so i tried as follows

```
public class sharedData
{
    public string GlobMeta;
    public int GlobValue;
    public sharedData(string meta, int value)
    {
        GlobMeta = meta;
        GlobValue= value;

    }
}
public class derivedData: sharedData
{
  public string test;
  test = string.Format("Shared meta = {0}, Shared Value = {1}",GlobMeta, GlobValue);
}
```

then use

```
var shared = new sharedData("desc", 1);
var derived = new derivedData();
var testData = derived.test;
```

so when i will create instance of derived it will use base (shared) values
wich is common to all derived classes.

how can i implement this, as my idea was to use less memory with large collections of data. and also clean code and ease of use.

Comment: Why are you formatting the values at all as part of the state of the object? I would suggest: a) following .NET naming conventions; b) avoiding public fields; c) looking up [constructor chaining](pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/constructors.html), which I think is what you're really talking about; d) not having a field for derived state like this - you might want to override `ToString` and use `string.Format` there, but I can't see why it would be part of your state... It's also not clear what you mean by "minimizing use of constructors in derived classes"...

Comment: Why not just use Static Variables for what is shared across all derived classes (assuming there is only one version of the data you are talking about.)

Comment: @JonSkeet i am aware of the issue of string format, it was only to demonstrate. though the issue is about inheritance. thanks for the info though....(:

Comment: @Mr.B i was trying to refrain using static but i guess in that case static will serve the cause just right.

Comment: @Jonesopolis i forgot to mention that the shared was ment to be a template to some different items to use the same structure though they cannot share the data as they are differ by theire values offcourse

Comment: @JonSkeet I am ~5 month stronger now... using (heavily) the approach of base.. factory & sealed at the bottom.. 'families' have been created since. it's a subset of .Net I am trying to come up with, ..same as webClient (example) as we see it, it's an abstraction of some heavy weight programming by Microsoft  developers. we just  **USE**  it, so I am taking it  few steps further.. via it's 'colleagues' and some ideas I have, I Construct a 'band'..  that I know many people would enjoy ... what they 'produce', just pass the correct params and you have an hour of work done in one (well 3) lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking along the same lines as Xiaoy312, and wrote this while he was posting his second example:

```
public class SharedData
{
    internal static string GlobMeta;
    internal static int GlobValue;

    public SharedData(string meta, int value)
    {
        GlobMeta = meta;
        GlobValue = value;
    }

    public SharedData(){}
}

public class DerivedData: SharedData
{
    public DerivedData() : base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Shared meta = {0}, Shared Value = {1}", GlobMeta, GlobValue);
    }
}
```

Declaring the static variables as 'internal means they will only be accessible in the scope of 'SharedData and any classes derived from it.

Comment: you answered 1) instanciable class for different versions i.e templating
2) non-parameterized derived data . bothe needs are met !

Answer (score 2):

You have declared a based class, `sharedData`, without parameterless constructor. Therefore, any class that inherit that class must define a base constructor. You can't rely on the the compiler do job the job for you anymore.

```
public class derivedData : sharedData
{
    public string test;

    public derivedData(string meta, int value) : base(meta, value)
    {
        // you can't do assignment in the class scope, unless it can be done statically, it has to be inside a method block
        test = string.Format("Shared meta = {0}, Shared Value = {1}", GlobMeta, GlobValue);
    }

    // or, if you prefer to have a parameterless ctor
    public derivedData() : base("a default value for meta", default(int))
    {
        test = string.Format("Shared meta = {0}, Shared Value = {1}", GlobMeta, GlobValue);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: It seems that you are using this for global settings, in that case, you need to mark `GlobMeta` and `GlobValue` as static. Otherwise they won't be "shared" at all between different instance of sharedData/derivedData.

You should consider rewriting it as this :

```
public static class SharedData
{
    public static string Meta { get; private set; }
    public static int Value { get; private set; }

    public static void SetData(string meta, int value)
    {
        Meta = meta;
        Value = value;
    }
}
public class DerivedData
{
    public string Test
    {
        get { return string.Format("Shared meta = {0}, Shared Value = {1}", SharedData.Meta, SharedData.Value); }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT 2 : If you need to have various instances of these, use the following :

```
public class SharedData
{
    public string Meta { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public SharedData(string meta, int value)
    {
        Meta = meta;
        Value = value;
    }
}
public class DerivedData : SharedData
{
    public string Test
    {
        get { return string.Format("Shared meta = {0}, Shared Value = {1}", Meta, Value); }
    }


    public DerivedData(string meta, int value) : base(meta, value)
    {
    }

    // note: this is a copy ctor, changing data after this has been created, will not affect this.
    public DerivedData(SharedData data) : base(data.Meta, data.Value)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: correct i do , though i did not interduce the issue of 'templating', wich intended to be for other subjects/kinds of 'users' of the class.

Comment: i.e same stracture != same values

Comment: @ Xiaoy, as i have sets of data, meaning each of them will use that same stracture but the values and parameters  are different

Comment: mybe incase your code within a non-static class and create instances for eache 'family' / kind of 'users' ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. See if edit#2 fits your needs.

Comment: thanks ,still it is not non-parameter dreived but as close as it can be (:

Comment: Since you have multiple instances of `SharedData` for each member of family, how does a DerivedData which data it should read from? You need to define that connection somehow. This is just one way of doing.